# Apple Watch Data Share

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, apple-watch

i'm facing a issue when trying to share data between Apple Watch and iPhone (both on simulator).

That's how i'm storing the data on my iPhone App:

```
    NSUserDefaults* defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc]initWithSuiteName:@"group.com.myapp"];
[defaults setObject:@"TEST" forKey:@"testKey"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

And that's how i'm trying to retrieve the data on my watch App:

```
NSUserDefaults* defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc]initWithSuiteName:@"group.com.myapp"];
    NSLog(@"%@",[defaults objectForKey:@"testKey"]);
```

It just returns NULL

I've configured the "appGroups" already, and my entitlements file looks like this:[image]

[image]

The entitlements file was empty, i've inserted this entitlement array manually. 

I've also tested in a brand new project and with the same steps i took, exept Xcode has generated this file properly, so it was automatic ant it worked like a charm.
 The project i'm trying to insert this is old one. I think it has something to do with that, but i have no idea how to fix it...

Can somebody help me with that?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What do you mean you couldn't get it working? Are you getting any error or exception? What are the NSLog messages?

Comment: The log just returns NULL... :/

Comment: I've inserted more details of the problem.... thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all who tried to help.... i found the solution... On new projects the Code Signing Entitlements are automatic... but in the old ones like mine we have to set it up manually.... Thanks very Much!!

[image]